# Not sure how to loop this correctly

Tags: python, selenium

I can't figure out how to loop this all correctly without something going wrong.

When it gets below 8000hp, it will say "process finished with exit code 0" in the console, which is weird as it should never stop running...

Basically, I need it to loop infinitely either attacking if >=8000 health + to make sure the enemy level + battle value conditions are met ( enemy level <=1 and BV <=51 )

if the enemy level or BV is >= , it should "search again"

if health <=8000 it should sleep until it has enough to fight again

Here is a test account to test for yourself:

user: testaccount123
pass: python123
Game: https://s9-en.bitefight.gameforge.com/user/login

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import re

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\JC 

WIN10\\PycharmProjects\\BitefightPvpBOT\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
driver.get("https://s9-en.bitefight.gameforge.com/user/login")  # SERVER 
LOGIN PAGE

driver.find_element_by_name("user").send_keys("testaccount123")  # USERNAME
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_name("pass").send_keys("python123")  # PASSWORD
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn-small").click()  # LOGIN BUTTON
time.sleep(1)

driver.get("https://s9-en.bitefight.gameforge.com/robbery/index") # HUNT PAGE
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_name("optionsearch").click() # Werewolf Hunt
time.sleep(2)

enemyLevel = int(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[.="Level:"]/following- 
sibling::td').text)
BV = int(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[.="Battle value:"]/following- 
sibling::td').text)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="gold"]')
HP = re.search(r'(\d+\.\d+)\s+/', elem.text).group(1)
HP = int(HP.replace('.', ''))

while enemyLevel <= 1 and BV <= 51 and HP >= 8000:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form/div/div/button").click() #Attack
        time.sleep(2)
        BattleReport = driver.find_element_by_id("reportResult")  # BATTLE REPORT
        print(BattleReport.text)  # OUTPUTS BATTLE REPORT
        time.sleep(2)
        print("------    ------")
        driver.get("https://s9-en.bitefight.gameforge.com/robbery/index")
        driver.find_element_by_name("optionsearch").click()  # Werewolf Hunt
        time.sleep(2)
else:
driver.find_element_by_name("optionsearch").click()
print("Finding new victim")
```

As you can tell I'm pretty awful at loops. How would I tackle this best? I tried a while loop, but couldn't get it to work correctly unless I was missing something.

Thanks and Kind regards

Comment: Your `else` is kicking you out of the `while`. Do you want it to just run indefinitely and only do certain actions under certain conditions?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Sending us to a remote site to test the problem is out of scope.

Comment: Yeah that's what I want to do. @C.Nivs

Comment: The remote site is what I'm using for a sandbox to aid me to learn python/selenium. Sorry for any inconvenience. Everything you need to sign in etc is in the code to help sort my issue. @Prune

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that your `else` is kicking you out of the loop. Refactoring to a `while True`, that will keep your program running. So copying down a lot of your code below for mostly complete code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import re

# login to your server here
# and set up driver

def get_new_enemy_stats(driver):
    # go to page to find enemy
    driver.get("https://s9-en.bitefight.gameforge.com/robbery/index") # HUNT PAGE
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_name("optionsearch").click() # Werewolf Hunt
    time.sleep(2)

    # get stats
    enemyLevel = int(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[.="Level:"]/following- 
    sibling::td').text)
    BV = int(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[.="Battle value:"]/following- 
    sibling::td').text)

    # return them
    return enemyLevel, BV


def get_health(driver):
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="gold"]')
    HP = re.search(r'(\d+\.\d+)\s+/', elem.text).group(1)
    HP = int(HP.replace('.', ''))
    return HP

while True:
    enemyLevel, BV = get_new_enemy_stats(driver)
    if enemyLevel > 1 or BV >51:
        # The stats are too high
        continue

    # do the attack
    HP = get_hp(driver)
    if HP<8000:
        # sleep_some
```

So what I've done is put getting the enemy stats to a function. This makes your code a bit more compact and *much* more readable. You want to get new stats when you need a new enemy.

Return the stats, check against `enemyLevel` and `BP`. If those tests fail, `continue` will skip the rest of the code and do another iteration of `while`. You can check your `HP` at the end, where if it's too low, you can sleep

`else` in a `while` loop is not contained *within* the loop. It functions like "while this, do that, else, do something else". That is why your loop was exiting and your script would complete

Comment: Ahh, right I see! thanks for the in-depth help + solution to my issue

Comment: @JCSmyth I made an edit where you'll probably want to get your health *after* a battle

Comment: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing line 48? @C.Nivs

Comment: @JCSmyth could be an issue with your `chromedriver`, what's the full stacktrace?

Comment: nvm fixed all issues ( i think ^^ ) thanks again! @C.Nivs

Comment: I let it run & after it slept for 5minutes, it instantly tried to fight again but ignored the HP rules and died? Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/JC WIN10/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/scratch_10.py", line 46, in <module>
    HP = get_health(driver)
  File "C:/Users/JC WIN10/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/scratch_10.py", line 34, in get_health
    HP = re.search(r'(\d+\.\d+)\s+/', elem.text).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' @C.Nivs

Comment: @JCSmyth that means your `re.search` call returns `None`. So it probably wasn't able to find your health stats for some reason. I'd check what `elem.text` is and if that's consistently returning the results you expect